# Why does choosemove() allow you to hit endlessly and not run lose() when the total value is greater then 21?

Tags: python, function

Is the code generating a new card every time choosemove() and then creating a new card again and adding on top if you hit again like its supposed to?
Basically, I need lose() to run when newtotalplayercardvalue > 21 so it shows the player lost, but it just lets you "hit" endlessly for some reason. Thanks in advance!

```
import random
def win():
  print ("")
  print("You won!") 
  menu()
def lose():
  print ("")
  print("You lost!")
  menu()
def numbertocard(card):
  if card == 11:
    card = "J"
  elif card == 12:
    card = "Q"
  elif card == 13:
    card = "K"
  elif card == 14:
    card = "A"
  else:
    card = card
  return card

def cardtonumber(cardvalue):
  if cardvalue == "J":
    cardvalue == 10
  elif cardvalue == "Q":
    cardvalue == 10
  elif cardvalue == "K":
    cardvalue = 10
  elif cardvalue == "A":
    cardvalue = 11
  else: cardvalue = cardvalue
  return (cardvalue)
    
def hit():
  print("")
  global totalplayercardvalue
  newcard = random.randint(1,14)
  new_card_name = numbertocard(newcard)
  print(f"You got a {new_card_name}")
  newtotalplayercardvalue = newcard + totalplayercardvalue
  if newtotalplayercardvalue > 21:
    lose()
  else:
    choosemove()
def stand():
  global totalplayercardvalue
  global totaldealercardvalue
  global dealercard2
  print(f"The dealer's second card is a {dealercard2}")
  if totalplayercardvalue > totaldealercardvalue:
    win()
  elif totaldealercardvalue > totalplayercardvalue:
    lose()
    
def choosemove():
  print("")
  choice = input("Would you like to hit or stand? \n")
  if choice == "hit":
    hit()
  elif choice == "stand":
    stand()
  else: 
    print("""Please only enter "hit" or "stand" """)
    choosemove()

def startgame():
  global totalplayercardvalue
  global totaldealercardvalue
  playercard1 = random.randint(1,14)
  p_card1_name = numbertocard(playercard1)
  print(f"Your first card is {p_card1_name}")
  print("")
  playercard2 = random.randint(1,14)
  p_card2_name = numbertocard(playercard2)
  print(f"Your second card is {p_card2_name}")
  print("")
  dealercard1 = random.randint(1,14)
  d_card1_name = numbertocard(dealercard1)
  dealercard2 = random.randint(1,14)
  totalplayercardvalue = playercard2 + playercard2
  totaldealercardvalue = dealercard1 + dealercard2
  if totalplayercardvalue == 21 and totaldealercardvalue == 21:
    tie()
  elif totalplayercardvalue == 21:
    win()
  elif totaldealercardvalue == 21:
    lose()
  else:
    print(f"The dealer's first card is a {d_card1_name}")
    choosemove()
      
    
def menu():
  play_game = input("Would you like to start a round? y/n: \n")
  if play_game == "y":
    startgame()
  else:
    print("""Say "y" """ )
    menu()

menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, your program isnt well formatted, there is no seperation between the way that global variables and local variables are defined. It's standard practice to define global variables in Uppercase. Will make life easier for you. 
As to what the endless hitting is, you aren't updating the totalplayercard variable in hit. You just define newtotalplayercardvalue, check if that is greater than 21 else choosing move, it doesn't update the global variable instead try

```
def hit():
  print("")
  global totalplayercardvalue

  newcard = random.randint(1,14)
  new_card_name = numbertocard(newcard)
  print(f"You got a {new_card_name}")

  totalplayercardvalue += newcard
  if totalplayercardvalue > 21:
    lose()
  else:
    choosemove()
```

IDK how black jack works however this is the reason that I can see